# Select Primary Key

Tags: .net, sql, datarow

[UPDATE: MS SQL Server 2005]

Hi is it possible to select a bunch of values, and then assign a column in the select statement as the primary key?

```
SELECT ID FROM HQ AS PRIMARYKEY -- this is wrong
SELECT Names FROM Stores
SELECT PRODUCTNAME FROM PRODUCTS
```

I ask this because I want to take advantage of the DataRow find method in .net, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After populating your dataset, you have to specify the primary key with the DataTable object, not in your sql query.

```
myTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {
    myTable.Columns["SomeColumn"]
};
```

Then you can use the Find() method

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think you can do that, that is have SQL server pass a ready index to the .NET app. You can add an index to the DataTable which will hold the data, it will be build on the client side.